# Find a basis for polynomials of degree less than $3$ such that $f'(-7) = f(1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

> Find a basis for polynomials of degree less than $3$ such that $f'(-7) = f(1)$

I let $ax^2 +bx +c$ represent polynomials of degree less than $3$ and set $f(1) = a+b+c$ be equal to $f'(-7) = -14a +b$.
Therefore, I get $15a + c = 0$.
I really don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you've almost done it. Now you have $c = -15 a$, and $b$ can be whatever, so $f(x) = ax^2 +bx - 15a = a(x^2 - 15) + bx$, so your basis is $\{x,x^2-15\}$.

Comment: ah ok thank you very much

Comment: @moony, you are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $b$ is free. Then you set $b=1$ and $a=0$. You have the first element of the basis $P_1(x)=x$. Now you set $b=0$ and $a=1$ and you obtain the second element of the basis $P_2(x)=x^2-15$ .

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful

Comment: @Vin.zaccaro,+1